# How distribute dynamically array buttons into layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to add dynamically created buttons in a (Gridview/LinearLayout/TableLayout) I don't know wich of them to use.
Each button has different width. Here is an example what I'm pretending to do:

**Actors:**

> [Button: Richard Gere]  [Button: Bla bla bla bla] [Button: Secondary
>   actor Bob] 
>   [Button: Ricardo Montoya]

**Genre:**

> [Button: Drama] [Button: Comedia]

**Cinemas:**

> [Button: Cinema Paradiso]  [Button: Cinema 2] [Button: Cinema 3] 
>   [Button: Cinema 4] .... [Button: Cinema N]

How can I distribute them dinamically?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to do it yourself?  Just put them into RelativeLayouts using layoutToRightOf, layoutBelow and width="wrap_content".

Comment: Unfortunately your looking at a custom layout if you want to wrap the length of the text and auto space to the line.
GridView wouldn't work, (its column base so everything would the same width). Table Layout would be your best bet just need to write some logic around IF space add to this Row ELSE add new row...

Comment: Thank you for the ideas guys. Question solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add them programmatically you can use horizontal linear layouts inside a vectical linear layout to keep your buttons.

Here is a sample code :

```
 LinearLayout InitQuiteSomeButtons(Button[] butts,int buttonsPerRow)
{

    LinearLayout vlay = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    vlay.setLayoutParams(vParams);
    vlay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout hLay=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams hParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    hLay.setLayoutParams(hParams);
    hLay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for (int i=0;i<butts.length;i++)
    {
        if (i>0 && i%buttonsPerRow==0)
        {
            vlay.addView(hLay);
            hLay = new LinearLayout(this);
            hLay.setLayoutParams(hParams);
            hLay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        }
        hLay.addView(butts[i]);

    }
    if (butts.length%buttonsPerRow==0)
    {
        //add the non-filledrow
        vLay.addView(hLay);
    }
    return vlay;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCMS for the snippet. What happens if the width of the button is dynamic due the text length of the button? How you can control this?

Comment: Then you can use the getWidth() function to figure out how large the button is, then you can adjust the number of buttons on the row according to the width of the inserted button.

So the loop becomes :
`
  for (int i=0;i<butt.length;i++)
{
   currentSpaceUsed+=butt[i].getWidth();
   if (currentSpaceUsed>ROW_WIDTH)
   {
     // create new horizontal layout
     currentSpaceUsed=0;
   }
   if (currentSpaceUsed>0)
   {
       //add the non-filled row
       vLay.addView(hLay);
   }
}
`

Comment: Thank you! I just implemented, worked like a charm. Problem solved.